# `Resource` library not work on `dart2native`

Tags: dart

I am using the Dart's `package:resource/resource.dart` to load a file, it works. 
But when I use `dart2native` to compile, it shows me the `Unsupported operation: Service isolate is not available.` May I know how can I resolve it?

The line for me to use the resource:

```
await Resource('package:core/assets/dev/ca.crt').readAsBytes()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `resource` package is not doing anything clever, it's just running `dart:io` code to load files and using `Isolate.resolvePackageUri` to figure out where the file is.

My guess it that the latter does not work when you compile to native. That makes a kind of sense - if you compile to native, you can move the executable somewhere else. It no longer has access to the source code. The `resource` package tries to load resources stored in package libraries, which is where the program source is also located, and a native application doesn't have that available.

I'm not sure if there is a way to make it work using the `resource` package.

I'd probably instead move the resource I need so it's distributed along with the executable, and then try to find the file relative to the executable path (if you can find that). Avoid using a `package:` URI, they generally won't work well with ahead-of-time compilation.